# Display results of API call on new site

Tags: javascript, html, api

I abstract an API behind my own API, which is called through a JavaScript function on my HTML page. The API call returns a piece of data (JSON). Now I want to navigate to another page, which displays the returned data. How can I pass the data returned by the API call to the new page? Or wouldn't it be better, to just pass the link to the new site and let it make the API call itself? But then again, how can I pass something to my new site?

That' my HTML with the JavaScript function call:

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Homepage</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="equity-frontend.js"></script>
  <div id="div1">
    <form>
      <label for="equity">Equity</label>
      <input type="text" name="equity" id="equity">
      <button onclick="sendRequest();return false">Get Data</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="target">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And that's the JavaScript file:

```
'use strict'

let baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/equities';

async function sendRequest() {
  let equity = document.getElementById('equity').value;
  let equityEndpoint = makeRequest(equity);
  callEndpoint(equityEndpoint).then(
    response => {
      let responseArr = [];


      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(response['_links'])) {
        let resObj = {};
        resObj['key'] = key;
        resObj['value'] = value['href'];
        responseArr.push(resObj);
      }
      let resDiv = document.createElement("div");

      for (let i = 0; i < responseArr.length; i++) {
        let btn = document.createElement('BUTTON');
        btn.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(responseArr[i].key);
        btn.onclick = function () {
          callEndpoint(baseUrl + responseArr[i].value)
            .then(response => {
              const tsDiv = document.createElement('div');
              const resP = document.createElement('p');
              resP.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response);
              tsDiv.appendChild(resP);
              document.body.insertBefore(tsDiv, resDiv)
            });
        }
        resDiv.appendChild(btn);
        resDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
      }

      let currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1");
      document.body.insertBefore(resDiv, currentDiv);
    }
  );
}

function makeRequest(equity) {
  let equityEndpoint = baseUrl + '/' + equity;
  return equityEndpoint;
}

async function callEndpoint(endpointUrl) {
  const response = await fetch(endpointUrl, {
    method: 'GET',
  });  
    let data = await response.json();
    return data;
}
```

I imagine something like a callback after i call my API like (pseudo code)

```
callEndpoint(baseUrl + responseArr[i].value)
.then(response => showResultPage(URL, response))
```

Which will receive the data from the response and navigates to the results.html, but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the data in [SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or a [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/Cookie) and read it in the next page.

Or you use advanced stuff like [ngrx/store](https://ngrx.io/guide/store).

Hope it help you a bit.

Comment: Thanks, SessionStorage seems to work for me!

Is this a proper way of doing what I want to achieve? It is just a project for university, but I imagine storing data/API URL in a browser storage isn't the most secure way. I know frameworks like React or Angular can do that, but how does it work under the hood? I'm also not a front-end expert, that's why i use plain HTML with JS, just to achieve something fast. :D

Comment: SessionStorage get lost when the session is over. So there should't be a security problem.
Angular, React,... are single page applications (SPA) there is no "real" page change and full reload. They have more possibilities to store data. But a store like "ngrx/store" is a very good solution.
 
For your approach is also a client-server solution possible. Client sends the final data to the server and the next page request this data again.

PS: If this answer is valid for you, please select it. ;-)

Comment: Right, forgot about the SPA thing. ;)

Alright, thanks again. What would be keywords for further research on this topic? Also I'll try the ngrx/store thing, if I find time and will report back (If I'll not forget to do :D ).

Comment: Great :-)  Next topics could be `API design`, `Single Responsibility Principle` and `session storage best practice`. Good luck!